# Initializing array of objects - Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object

I have an array of objects and when I try to access to it, I get an error saying:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'ID' of undefined

My code is the following:

```
export class Carimplements OnInit {
  pieces: Piece[] = [];

  test(pos){
    this.pieces[pos].ID = "test";
  }
}
```

being Piece an object

```
export class Piece{
    ID: string;
    doors: string;
}
```

I call to `test(pos)` from the HTML with a valid position.

I guess that I am trying to access to the position X of an array that has not been initialized. How could I do it? Is it possible to create a constructor?

Comment: Don't you mean this to be: `pieces: Piece[] = [];`?

Comment: Yes sorry, that's been just a typo. But the error keeps persisting.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- Correct syntax for defining array types in TypeScript is this:

  ```
  pieces: Piece[] = [];
  ```
- The error is a runtime error. When you run your app you have an empty array `pieces` (but the variable still initialized with `[]`) but you call `test(whatever)` which tries to access an array element `whatever` that doesn't exist.

  You can do for example this:

  ```
  pieces: Piece[] = [{
    ID: '1',
    doors: 'foo'
  }];
  ```

  and then test this method with `test(0)`.

Comment: pieces = Piece[] = [] was just a typo. I meant pieces: Piece[] = []; But the error keeps persisting.

Comment: Can you make a demo?

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
export class Carimplements OnInit {
  pieces: Piece[] = [];

  test(pos){
    this.pieces[pos] = {ID: "test"};
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let pieces: Piece[]  = [];

//initialize object before assigning value
test(pos){
    this.pieces[pos] = new Piece();
    this.pieces[pos].ID = "test";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following method

```
 test(pos){
    if(pos < this.pieces.length)
      this.pieces[pos].ID = "test";
    else
      // throw error
  }
```

Comment: No. Pos is correct. Actually in this case I am trying to access to pos = 0, which is the first one.